# Create new Web Service Endpoint in Acumatica

Tags: json, api, post, acumatica

I am new with Acumatica Web Service Endpoints. I have used couple of examples of how I can get the data from certain tables, but the thing is that I want to make one new API link, which will be used as POST from one external app.
When the data is sent, my Graph would take the data, and use the existing DACs to save the sent data....I already have all the DACs so in general I would need to :

- provide a link for external POST call
- when called, to authenticate the user and in case that the authentication is ok
- to receive the data, and convert it into my objects....
- save the data and the attachments
- logout
  Is Acumatica that much flexible ? When the data is received, the easiest way is to use the Newtonsoft json to convert into object...but that is also not the case here....
  I am pretty confused which approach I can use....any suggestions?
  All of this methods I have used within simple console app...but Acumatica is much more complex....

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `IWebhookHandler` of Acumatica for the creation of the Incoming Webhooks.

Below is a demo implementation of that interface

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.Webhooks;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Results;

namespace DemoIncomingWebhook
{
    public class MyDemoWebhook : IWebhookHandler
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class MyDemoWebhookResponse
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Mesage { get; set; }
        }
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //     In this method, the developer needs to process a request from an external application,
            //     including the following:
            //     • Process authentication information in the request
            //     • Transform the data in external format to the data that can be saved in Acumatica ERP
            //     • Invoke graph methods that save the data in Acumatica ERP

            return await Task.FromResult(new JsonResult<MyDemoWebhookResponse>(new MyDemoWebhookResponse
            {
                Status = "Success",
                Mesage = "Demo webhook worked!"
            }, new JsonSerializerSettings(),Encoding.ASCII,request));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to register your webhook on the Webhooks page, Acumatica will generate the URL when the record is saved.

[image]

After that, you can use webhook and send a POST request to it
[image]